# NullReferenceError with linq to PostgreSQL

Tags: c#, postgresql, linq, nullreferenceexception, linq2db

I have proyect that use linq to postgresql,  I have the library and Its three dependencies.

But when I try to connect to de DB I get this error:

First chance of Exception of type ' `System.NullReferenceException` ' in `linq2db.dll`. Additional information: `Object reference not set to an instance of an object. (Translated).`

Stack trace:

> in LinqToDB.Data.DataConnection..ctor(String configurationString) in
>   i:\linq2db\Source\Data\DataConnection.cs:line 41  in
>   LinqToDB.Data.DataConnection..ctor() in
>   i:\linq2db\Source\Data\DataConnection.cs:line 24    in
>   modelo.BDGestion.bdgestionDB..ctor() in d:\Proyectos\Proyectos 
>   VisualStudio\TimeSheets\TimeSheets\modelo\BDGestion.PostgreSQL.generated.cs:línea
>   44    en TimeSheets.SeleccionPersonal..ctor() in
>   d:\Proyectos\Proyectos
>   VisualStudio\TimeSheets\TimeSheets\SeleccionPersonal.cs:line 23

```
public partial class SeleccionPersonal : Form
    {
        public SeleccionPersonal()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            try
            {
                using (var db = new bdgestionDB())
                {

                }
            }catch(Exception ex){
                MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
            }
        }
    }
```

I generated the classes using the template, the connection String is well formed and properly added to de connectionStrings. Checked it by me in this solution and by a friend in other computer by its own. If you need any information just ask.

Generated class:

```
public partial class bdgestionDB : LinqToDB.Data.DataConnection
{
    tables...

    public bdgestionDB()
    {
        InitDataContext();
    }

    public bdgestionDB(string configuration)
        : base(configuration)
    {
        InitDataContext();
    }

    partial void InitDataContext();
}
```

The App.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
  </startup>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="Postgres" connectionString="Server=thot-test;Port=5432;Database=bdgestion;UserId=test;Password=T15Pmc;Pooling=true;MinPoolSize=10;MaxPoolSize=100;Protocol=3;"/>
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: The problem it's not the NulReferenceException, i don't use an object by my self! Please, read the code before say that it's duplicated.

Comment: The exception indicates that your connectionString is incorrect and this leads to a Null reference.

Comment: What is configuration?

Comment: The connectionString is: Server=thot-test;Port=5432;Database=bdgestion;UserId=test;Password=test;Pooling=true;MinPoolSize=10;MaxPoolSize=100;Protocol=3; and works when i use it with Npgsql directly, my friend uses a different one and same problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I  googled the source snipped and got pointed in the direction of [this file](https://github.com/linq2db/linq2db/blob/master/Source/Data/DataConnection.cs).

Looking at the line 41, it tries to access MappingSchema from DataProvider. 
From this it looks like the DataProvider is null. Googling some more I found [this page](https://github.com/linq2db/linq2db). Looks like you're missing provider name in your connection string:

```
<add name="Northwind" 
connectionString = "Server=.\;Database=Northwind;Trusted_Connection=True;Enlist=False;" 
providerName     = "PostgreSQL" />
```

[Here](https://github.com/linq2db/examples/tree/master/PostgreSQL/GetStarted) you can find an example of using Linq2db, connecting to the PostgreSQL database.

Comment: Yeah, that was the error. I didn't search the source but is a good tip to follow. C# have a good documentation when things work but nothing when  goes wrong.

Comment: I used this template, but the one that Nuget download doesn't have the providerName att. Please, watch it carefully.